# FolderNameEditor not working with PropertyGrid

Tags: propertygrid

When using FolderNameEditor in my settings class, I cannot get it to display the ellipsis so I can change the folder.  The code for my property is below.

Is there another attribute that I need?  Change a setting on an existing attribute?  Is there an alternative to FolderNameEditor, other than writing my own editor?

```
    [Category("Schedule")]
    [DisplayName("File Path")]
    [Editor(typeof(FolderNameEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    [ExpandableObject]
    [UserScopedSetting()]
    [DefaultSettingValue(@"c:\temp")]
    public string ScheduleFilePath
    {
        get { return _scheduleFilePath; }
        set { _scheduleFilePath = value; }
    }
```

My settings class inherits from ApplicationSettingsBase.  I have many other properties (fonts and colors) in my settings class and they work fine.

Specifying the FolderNameEditor seems to have no effect, I am only allowed to edit the property as a string.  I tried the ExpandableObject property, but it just displays the length of the string.

Is there a decent alternative to PropertyGrid?  I seem to spend an inordinate amount of time getting it to work.

Comment: For the ellipsis button to appear, you need to focus on the property in the pgrid. Other than that, I can't reproduce your problem, all work fine, so if you want help, please provide a reproducing piece of code.

Comment: Here is my XAML:
<ext:PropertyGrid Name="propGrid" ShowSearchBox="False" ShowSortOptions="False" />

I am using the Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit:
xmlns:ext="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"

_scheduleFilePath is declared as a string

I assign SelectedObject in my Dlg.xaml.cs file:
this.propGrid.SelectedObject = settings;

Comment: XAML? ok. you're confusing the Winforms Property Grid and xceed's WPF one. Then don't share the same technologies (and editors...)

Comment: I guess I thought the editors would be compatible.  Since xceed didn't implement a folder browser editor, I guess I'll have to do that myself.  Fortunately, there is a pretty good example on the web site.